# Return data from a Flask API

Tags: python, rest, react-native, flask

I've made this request in my React Native application which sends over some data to process.

```
await fetch('http://192.168.5.12:5000/login', {
method: 'post', 
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  data: result.user.email
 })
});
```

This route handles the data receiving, processing and should handle returning the variable `result` to the React Native application.

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    email = request.json['data']
    id = session.query(Users.id).filter(Users.estudent_email==email)
    result = users_schema.dump(id)
    return jsonify(result)
```

The requesting sending and processing work properly, verified by testing the request sending with webhook.site and the back-end part with Postman. Now my issue is that I don't know how to fetch the returning data (result) with my React Native application and use it there.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Edited the main post to explain the issue better and include more code.

Comment: What's the exact problem now? Any errors? Result is not being returned?

Comment: No errors. Everything works fine. The issue is that I don't know how to fetch the `result` variable with the React Native application and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to assign the results of `fetch()` to a variable for further manipulation or you need to handle the resolve promise the call will return.

```
let myresult = await fetch(...)
```

or

```
fetch(...)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          // handle result
        },
        (error) => {
          // handle error
          });
        }
      )
```